# How to compile apache/httpd on Linux?

Tags: apache, compilation

I am trying to compile https://github.com/apache/httpd on Linux.

1. It does **not** have `./configure` script in the repo.
2. It does **not** have `./autoconf` script in the repo.
3. Nor does it have a `Makefile` (default) for make.

I couldn't information in the README or INSTALL file in the repo to compile from source.

How do I compile https://github.com/apache/httpd on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into an error, APR not installed when I tried `./buildconf`

The following steps worked.

1. Download apr source from Apache website
2. Download apr-util source from Apache website.

> ./buildconf --with-apr=/home/senthil/Downloads/apr-1.7.0/ --with-apr-util=/home/senthil/Downloads/apr-util-1.6.1
>
> ./configure
>
> make

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
./buildconf
```

As Senthil Kumaran answered his question, you can add `--with-apr=/path/to/apr --with-apr-util=/path/to/apr-util`

Then do the rest.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/configure.html

### A little tutorial to do the rest:

Usually needs libssl, libnghttp2, libexpat, libpcre, apr, apr-util

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/install/apache --enable-mpms-shared=all --enable-mods-shared=reallyall
```

Then:

```
make && make install
```

From next time, to use the same configuration:

```
make clean && ./config.nice && make && make install
```

Comment: I had to point the ./buildconf to the apr and ap-util sources.